# Python can't connect to phpmyadmin mysql database conection refused

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i'am trying to connect with python to my mysql database running PHPmyadmin. But he connection is refused: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.1:3306' (10061 connection refused)

I'am using this script:

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="192.168.1.1",
  user="root", 
  password="root",
 database="wine2"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

I have no problems using the graphical interface of phpmyadmin to login with this credentials.

Phpmyadmin is running on a raspery pi in my network.

Pls help

Comment: Thats because phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP and is definitely no a DBMS :)

Comment: connection refused could be that the MySQL server is not running OR that the firewall is blocking you

Comment: The 192.168.1.1 address is also suspicious (if it is a /24), login to your pi over SSH and try to run your python code there (change the host to localhost (127.0.0.1)).

Comment: i ran my testcode there and it is working on the raspery with local address 127.0.0.1, mysql server is running and address 192.168.1.1/24 is correct so maybe a firewall issue

Comment: run `sudo netstat -tlpnu | grep 3306` and see if it is listening for `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` if first one is teh case, you might need to ask mysql to listen to all ports(which is not recommended in production setup, but in local network, it is fine)

Comment: Thx for you reply but `sudo netstat -tlpnu | grep 3306 ` gives no output

Answer (score 0):

After a time I found a solution. The bind address was incorrect.

Go to

```
cd /etc/mysql/ maria.conf.d/
```

Edit 50-server.cnf

```
bind-address: 127.0.0.1
```

to whatever your IP is.